# Vue.js connected data for multiple select option

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application, vue-component

Here is my **code**

```
                <li>
                  <select v-model="selectYear" id="search-year" class="w-100 text-center mb-1" name="year" >
                    <option v-for="year in years" v-bind:value="year.value">
                      {{ year.text }}
                    </option>
                  </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <select v-model="selectMake" class="w-100 text-center mb-1" name="make">
                    <option v-for="make in makes" v-bind:value="make.value">
                      {{ make.text }}
                    </option>
                  </select>
                </li>
```

and the components data:

```
export default {
  name: 'search',
  data: function () {
    return{
      selectYear: '2017',
      years: [
        { text: '2017', year: '2017' },
        { text: '2016', year: '2016' },
        { text: '2015', year: '2015' }
      ],
      selectMake: '',
      makes: [
        { text: 'Sony', value: 'Sony', year: '2017' },
        { text: 'Asus', value: 'Asus', year: '2017' },
        { text: 'IPhone', value: 'IPhone', year: '2016'}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**What I want**
I have multiple select options that is connected in terms of what only to show depending on the previous selected option.

**For example**

*Scenario 1*: Year Selected: 2017

```
        Select Make Options Available: ['Sony','Asus']
```

*Scenario 2:* Year Selected: 2017

```
        Select Make Options Available: ['Iphone']
```

*Scenario 3:* Year Selected: None

```
        Select Make Options Available: []
```

Is it possible to implement in Vue.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a typical case where you would use [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) values.

add a computed value `filteredMakes` to [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) `makes` based on `selectYear`

```
computed: {
    filteredMakes() {
        return this.makes.filter((obj, i) => {
            return obj.year === this.selectYear
        });
    }
}
```

and use the computed value in the v-for for option

```
<option v-for="make in filteredMakes" v-bind:value="make.value">
```

`filteredMakes` will be updated automatically everytime `selectYear` changes. ain't Vue magical ?

Comment: more info pls? perhaps a jsfiddle demo ?

Comment: maybe the .filter is not working because whenever i try return this.makes , it returns the whole data

Comment: `<option v-for="year in years" v-bind:value="year.value">` this is the problem. year object (`{ text: '2017', year: '2017' }`) has no key named `value`. so it should be `v-bind:value="year.year"`